# Apply cpu transition to cc_binary rule in Bazel

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I've a c target that always must be compiled for `darwin_x86_64`, no matter the `--cpu` set when calling bazel build. It's the only target that always must be compiled for a specific cpu in a big project.

```
cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["hello-world.cc"],
)
```

In the bazel documentation it seems to be possible to do this using transitions. Maybe something like:

```
def _force_x86_64_impl(settings, attr):
    return {"//command_line_option:cpu": "darwin_x86_64"}

force_x86_64 = transition(
    implementation = _force_x86_64_impl,
    inputs = [],
    outputs = ["//command_line_option:cpu"]
)
```

But how do I tie these two together? I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't seem to find the relevant documentation over at bazel.build.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the transition defined, now you need to [attach it to a rule](https://bazel.build/rules/config#user-defined-transitions).

```py
r = rule(
    implementation = _r_impl,
    attrs = {
        "_allowlist_function_transition": attr.label(
            default = "@bazel_tools//tools/allowlists/function_transition_allowlist",
        ),
        "srcs": attr.label(cfg = force_x86_64),
    },
)

def _r_impl(ctx):
    return [DefaultInfo(files = ctx.attr.srcs[0][DefaultInfo].files)]
```

This defines a rule that attaches the appropriate transition to the `srcs` you pass it, and then simply forwards the list of files from [DefaultInfo](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/DefaultInfo). Depending on what you're doing, this might be sufficient, or you might also want to forward the runfiles contained in `DefaultInfo` and/or other providers.

Comment: This is interesting. To complete the example, you'd then create a new rule:

`r(label="my_forced_binary", srcs="hello-world")`

Is there any way to inject the configuration into `cc_binary` through a macro? Or force the entire build graph to adopt a transition no matter what?

Comment: You could definitely wrap that in a macro which creates `r(name=name, srcs=name + "__impl"); cc_binary(name=name + "__impl", **kwargs)`. If you want to apply it to the top-level build targets, just use command line flags (`--cpu=darwin_x86_64`). You can't want to apply it to the entire build graph, things like host transitions will change it further.

Answer (score -1):

Use [target_compatible_with](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/common-definitions.html#common.target_compatible_with)

Example (only compiled on Windows):

```
cc_library(
    name = "win_driver_lib",
    srcs = ["win_driver_lib.cc"],
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
        "@platforms//os:windows",
    ],
)
```